# How to Install a Driver as Part of a Winforms App

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, driver

I am currently working on a WinForms app in Visual Studio 2019, which uses a USB to I2C adapter to read EEPROM register values from a device. The manufacturer of the adapter provides the driver for the device in a downloadable zip file on their website which contains the .inf and .sys files among other things. I would like to have it so when the end user installs the app, the driver is automatically installed as well. What is the best way to do this? I have a Setup project in my solution, which I can use to put the driver files in the application folder, but that doesn't mean the driver is actually set up.

I found one potential solution that used `System.Configuration.Install`, but my targeted framework at the moment is .NET core 3.1, which unlike .NET framework does not have that namespace. I am only expecting users to use Windows 10, so I theoretically could switch to .NET framework for that namespace if necessary. However, I don't know if that will break anything in the app or if that is the easiest way to go about this.

I am very new to deploying apps so I really don't know the best way to go about this. Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are third-party .net core ways of doing this, such as

[Core.System.Configuration.Install](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Core.System.Configuration.Install/)

> Porting of System.Configuration.Install for .NET Core. (.NET 4.0
> version)

Use at your own risk

however, there are also oodles of installers that have this capabilities.

Lastly, this can also be done with powershell, P/invoke and I believe there was talk in github about [releasing this source code](http://Installer-related%20classes%20missing) however you will need to track that down and follow the trail yourself

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer. Could you give an example or two of the installers you are referring to? I honestly don't know of any or how to get started with them.

Comment: Hi @Andromecles check out wix. However, my answer was mainly just trying to point you to the nuget package and the GitHub page. Unfortunately i don't have time to give an example of a third party installation suite